# How do I check if there are DAGs running in Airflow (before restarting Airflow)?

Tags: airflow

I need to restart Airflow. I want to make sure I do it when it's idle, so I that I don't interrupt a job by restarting the worker component of Airflow.

How do I see what DAGs are running?

I don't see anything in the UI that would list currently running DAGs.

I don't see any command in the `airflow` CLI to list currently running DAGs.

I found `airflow shell` that lets me connect to the DB, but I don't know enough about Airflow internals to know where to look to see what's running.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also query the database to get all running tasks at once:

```
select * from task_instance where state='running'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the command line command `airflow jobs check` which would return "No alive jobs found." in the event no jobs are running.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Browse > DAG Runs > Search > Add Filter "State" with "running"

Or use the below address on your browser:

/dagrun/list/?_flt_0_state=running

Answer (score 0):

I found it... it's in the UI, on the DAGs page, it's the second circle under "Recent Tasks":

[image]